# Run this function to work in background

Tags: c#, asynchronous, background, task, .net-4.5

```
    private void CommandtWatcher()
    {
        // Both PR and D2H are classes from external dll files
        // PR is ProcessMemoryReader class, it reads a message from X window
        if(PR[0].getLastChatMsg().Equals("#eg"))    // If I typed "#eg" then
        {
            D2HList[0].QuitGame("WindowToBeClosed"); // Close game window
        }
    }
```

These function works pretty nice, but I can't force it to work in background without interrupting UI life

And this is not a snippet from game core source code, it's rather totally external program reading process memory so I don't have any kind of superpowers

Comment: What version of .NET are you on?  This affects how easy a background task is to start.

Comment: I have a .NET 4.5 version for this project :)

Comment: In that case, I recommend @NedStoyanov 's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET 4.5 you can use `Task.Run` to do this. I'd also change the method to return the resulting `Task`. That way clients of the code can choose whether to `await` the result or ignore it if the wish to do a fire and forget.

```
private Task CommandtWatcher()
{
     return Task.Run(() =>
     {
         // Both PR and D2H are classes from external dll files
         // PR is ProcessMemoryReader class, it reads a message from X window
         if(PR[0].getLastChatMsg().Equals("#eg"))    // If I typed "#eg" then
         {
             D2HList[0].QuitGame("WindowToBeClosed"); // Close game window
         }
     }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
private void CommandtWatcher()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Both PR and D2H are classes from external dll files
        // PR is ProcessMemoryReader class, it reads a message from X window
        if(PR[0].getLastChatMsg().Equals("#eg"))    // If I typed "#eg" then
        {
            D2HList[0].QuitGame("WindowToBeClosed"); // Close game window
            return;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100); // Prevent hogging cpu
    }
}
```

And to run in the background:

```
Task.Run((Action)CommandWatcher);
```

This will run the method in a new thread, separately from the UI, waiting for the `LastChatMsg` to be `#eg` and then perform logic and stop.

Comment: I'd use `await Task.Delay` this way you don't use up a thread while you are sleeping.